Cant use selenium to send automatic messages
I am trying to send messages to every unsaved contact on WhatsApp Web, and I have been working with a script provided by ChatGPT using Selenium. However, I’m having trouble identifying the right element with XPath to open each individual chat in the app. Specifically, I need a way to interact with each contact and send them a message.
Additionally, I want to automate scrolling so that all chats are loaded, ensuring that every unsaved contact receives the same message. I’m also adding a 15-second delay between each message to avoid being flagged as spam by WhatsApp.
Could you help me with the XPath to select each chat dynamically or suggest a better approach to automate this task?
This is the code chat gpt generated
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

# Set up Chrome options to run headless (optional)
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Uncomment this line if you want to run headless

# Set up the webdriver with ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

# Open WhatsApp Web
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")

# Wait for the page to load (add time for QR code scan if necessary)
WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#pane-side > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > div._ak8l"))
)

# Now you can interact with elements. For example, sending a message:
# Assuming that you want to interact with the first contact on the list:

# Click on the first chat
first_chat = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#pane-side > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > div._ak8l")
first_chat.click()

# Wait for the message input field to be visible
message_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div._13NKt"))
)

# Send a message
message_box.send_keys("Hello! This is an automated message.") 
message_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Optional: Add a delay between sending messages to avoid being flagged as spam
time.sleep(15)

# Don't forget to close the browser after you're done
driver.quit()```



Please note that ("Generative artificial intelligence [...] tools may not be used to generate content for Stack Overflow.")[https://stackoverflow.com/help/gen-ai-policy]. Provide a more detailed description of the issue, go through the code, try to isolate the line(s) causing the issue, give instructions on how to reproduce, and edit the post to include the above information.
